# Why / How is Adobe Premier Pro CC using over 100% of my CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, adobe-premiere

So I've started a render. My MacBook Pro starts smelling like burnt feet. I open activity monitor and see the following:

[image: ummmm]

So currently with those two processes alone I'm running over 300% of my CPUs capacity.

I then look at the chart at the bottom of activity monitor and see the following:

[image: ummmm]

60% idle?

After I disconnected the charger computer decided to hibernate, so plugged back in and still with impossible cpu usage.

I'm afraid my MacBook's going to melt. Why/how can CPU usage be so high?

Comment: You're likely seeing this because Premier utilizes multi-threading, which makes use of the multiple cores inside all modern CPUs.

Comment: @nc4pk I would suspect that activity monitor could take that into account, just seems a really bizarre reading that I've never encountered with other applications.

Comment: @downvoters mind explaining yourself?

Comment: btw, can't actually answer this for sure, but if the temperature is ramping heavily & you can smell something which doesn't smell particularly 'electrical' then suspect dust-bunnies & think about getting the machine cleaned. If it does smell electrical, definitely get it checked out.

Comment: Yes well I've started getting the screen of death from the Mac, you know the 'your computer restarted due to a problem' black screen, during the render. I think you are right, time to get a clean or perform one myself. @Tetsujin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity monitor's 'per app' view shows "percentage of one core" which a really odd way to do it, to my mind.

This means that on a 4-core CPU with Hyperthreading, you are seeing what appears to be 8 times the actual load. The User total underneath is [imo] correctly showing the composite total load on the entire CPU.

The "percentage of one core" value is why you see many posts claiming *xxx process is using 500% of my CPU*